# Yank current file path and line number into system clipboard

Tags: cut-copy-paste

I'm trying to save the current relative path of my file and line number into my clipboard.
I would like to have `application/models/my_model.rb:34`

But I don't understand how [expand](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#expand()) works.

They have this example :

```
Example:
            :let &tags = expand("%:p:h") . "/tags"
```

But I failed when I want to combine relative path `expand("%:h")` and file_name `expand("%:t")`.

```
:echom expand("%:h:t") . ':' . line(".")
```

returns `model:34`

Any ideas ?

Comment: I don't get it ...  `%:h` is not the relative path - it's (the path - filename). Wouldn't just `expand('%') . ':' . line(".")` do? For example, I get `.vim/vimrc:1` when I run `vim .vim/vimrc` from `~`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should just use `expand('%')`.

If I do:

```
cd ~/..; vim ~/.vim/vimrc
```

Then, in Vim:

```
:echo join([expand('%'),  line(".")], ':')
muru/.vim/vimrc:1
```

Or with `cd ~/Documents; vim ~/.vim/vimrc`:

```
:echo join([expand('%'),  line(".")], ':') join([expand('%:h'), expand('%:t')], '/')
/home/muru/.vim/vimrc:1 /home/muru/.vim/vimrc
```

`expand('%:h')` does not offer any advantages here. Doing `expand("%:h") . '/' . expand("%:t")` is just going to give you back `expand('%')`, with the added problem that you lose portability - `/` is not always the correct separator.

Side note: [`join()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#join%28%29) is a convenient function for joining strings with separators. Not necessary here, where we have only two items, but could be useful if you add more strings.

Comment: I like how you used `join()` that's a good reminder that this function can be pretty useful.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it to combine expand :

```
:echom expand("%:h") . '/' . expand("%:t") . ':' . line(".")
```